# Many NSolves to interpolating function

Tags: equation-solving, interpolation

I have an expression of the form:

```
expr = TerribleNumericalFunction[U[p]] == SimpleFunction[p]
```

The `Simple` function is a polynomial, and the `Terrible` function involves elliptic integrals.  I want to invert this, solving for `U` as a function of `p` as an interpolating function .

Naively, I would plug in `p=0` and solve for `U[0]`.  Then I could repeat this for many values of `p` and interpolate.  **Is there a better method?**  I feel like there should be a way to vectorize this process.

As a test case, this expression is way faster to evaluate than mine:

```
expr = Sqrt[0.04 + U[p] + U[p]^2] == 2.0 + 3.0*p;
soln = Table[0, {i, 0, 99}];
For[p = 0, p < 100, p++,
  soln[[p]] = NSolve[expr, U[p]]
]
```

This gets me a list of values (as substitution rules).  This also gives 2 roots per `p`, which is true for my actual case.

**How do I best turn my list of substitutions into a list of points for `Interpolation`?**  I guess there should really be two interpolating functions... one for each branch of `U`.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I might do the simple example like this, with a differential-algebraic equation, assuming initial points on each branch are given (`U10`, `U20`) -- had the wrong code before:

```
Clear[U, U1, U2, x, p];
{U10, U20} = U[0] /. NSolve[expr /. p -> 0, U[0]]; (* initial values *)

{sol} = NDSolve[{
  expr /. {{U -> U1}, {U -> U2}},  (* implicit equation*)
  {U1[0], U2[0]} == {U10, U20},    (* initial condition *)
  x'[p] == 1, x[0] == 0},          (*dummy ODE,to force interpolation of U1,U2*)
 {U1, U2}, {p, 0, 100}]
(*
  {{U1 -> InterpolatingFunction[{{0., 100.}}, <>], 
    U2 -> InterpolatingFunction[{{0., 100.}}, <>]}}
*)
```

Not a particularly interesting equation to plot:

```
GraphicsRow[{
  Plot @@ {Through[{U1, U2}[p]] /. sol, 
    Flatten@{p, U1["Domain"] /. sol},
    AspectRatio -> 1, Frame -> True, Axes -> False},
  ContourPlot[
   Evaluate[expr /. U[p] -> U],
   {p, 0, 100}, {U, -300, 300}]
  }]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do can be accomplished pretty simply by rewriting your expression as a function.

```
eqn[p_] := Sqrt[0.04 + u + u^2] == 2.0 + 3.0 p

uPts = Table[Flatten[{p, NSolve[eqn[p], u][[All, 1, 2]]}], {p, 0, 99}];
u1 = Interpolation[uPts[[All, {1, 2}]]];
u2 = Interpolation[uPts[[All, {1, 3}]]]

Plot @@ {Through[{u1, u2}[t]], Flatten[{t, u1["Domain"]}], 
           AspectRatio -> 1, PlotLegends -> {"u1", "u2"}}
```

[image: plot]

Answer (score 0):

To set up the points for interpolation, I used two `Table`s.

```
pts1 = Table[{p, U[p] /. soln[[p, 1]]}, {p, 0, 99}];
pts2 = Table[{p, U[p] /. soln[[p, 2]]}, {p, 0, 99}];
U1 = Interpolation[pts1];
U2 = Interpolation[pts2];
```

I still think there should be a better way than a `For` loop.  It is terribly slow.