# Solve `f(x)=0` with a parameter

Tags: equation-solving

I want to solve `f(x)=0` with following code (with a parameter):

```
 $Assumptions = \[Lambda] > 0; 
    f[x_] := x - \[Lambda]*Cosh[x/4]; 
    FindRoot[f[x] == 0, {x, 0}]
    N[FindInstance[f[x] == 0, x, Reals, 2]]
    N[Reduce[f[x] == 0, x, Reals]]
    NSolve[f[x] == 0, x, Reals]
    N[Solve[f[x] == 0, x, Reals]]
```

But I do not have any solution. 
I can  solve `f(x)=0` for following code (without parameter):

```
f[x_] := x - Cosh[x/4]; 
FindRoot[f[x] == 0, {x, 0}]
N[FindInstance[f[x] == 0, x, Reals, 2]]
N[Reduce[f[x] == 0, x, Reals]]
NSolve[f[x] == 0, x, Reals]
N[Solve[f[x] == 0, x, Reals]]
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: You will likely have to provide numerical values for $\lambda$. Make a table over the $\lambda$ values and solve for each case numerically using `NSolve` or `FindRoot`.

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/79840/many-nsolves-to-interpolating-function

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you are trying to create a function `x[λ]` you could use [`NDSolveValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolveValue):

```
if = NDSolveValue[
    {D[x[λ] - λ Cosh[x[λ]/4] == 0, λ], x[0] == 0},
    x,
    {λ, -5, 5}
]
```

> NDSolveValue::ndsz: At λ == -2.65097, step size is effectively zero; singularity or stiff system suspected.
>
> NDSolveValue::ndsz: At λ == 2.6509731117978133`, step size is effectively zero; singularity or stiff system suspected.
>
> InterpolatingFunction[{{-2.65097, 2.65097}}, <>]

Here is a plot:

```
Plot[if[t], {t, -2.65, 2.65}]
```

[image]

Comment: It's strange to receive a downvote for this answer!

Comment: +1 I think this is a clever approach, but can we force the second solution somehow?

Answer (score 1):

```
f[x_, λ_] := x - λ*Cosh[x/4];
```

The [`ContourPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ContourPlot.html) for this function is

```
cplt = ContourPlot[f[x, λ], {λ, 0, 3}, {x, -2, 25},
  Contours -> Range[-3, 3],
  ContourStyle -> Lighter[Gray, 0.6],
  ContourShading -> None,
  FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 14, Bold] & /@ {λ, x}),
  PlotPoints -> 150]
```

[image]

The points on the contour for `f[x, λ]==0` are

```
pts = Cases[cplt, {x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ} /; Abs[f[y, x]] < 10^-6, 
   Infinity];

Show[cplt, Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[2], Point[pts]}]
```

[image]

For `f[x, λ]==0`, `x` is not a simple function of `λ` since it is multi-valued. Consequently, it would be easier to express `λ` as a function of `x`

```
pts2 = Sort[Reverse /@ pts];
```

The [`InterpolationFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InterpolationFunction.html) for these points is

```
if = Interpolation[pts2];

Plot[if[x],
 {x, 0, 25},
 Frame -> True, Axes -> False,
 FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 14, Bold] & /@ {x, λ})]
```

[image]